# Using index to speed up child <> parent query

Tags: oracle, indexing, full-table-scan

I have query similar to this:

```
select *
from table1
where status = 'ACTV'
and child_id <> parent_id
```

The problem is that this table is quite and large and Oracle is doing full table scan.
I was trying to create an index (with status, child_id, parent_id columns) that would speed up this query but Oracle is not using this index even with hint.

Is there a way to speed up this query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index with function:

```
CREATE INDEX child_parent ON table1(DECODE(child_id,parent_id,1, 0))
```

And then use it in your select:

```
select *
from table1
where status = 'ACTV'
  and DECODE(child_id,parent_id,1, 0) = 0
```

Only cons for this solution - it will slow down insert and update operations a bit more than regular index.
Also if potentially returnable record count is large Oracle can do table full scan

Comment: Thank You for information. This table has already few indexes and using DECODE allows to do an INDEX SKIP SCAN with DECODE and status column as data filters.

Answer (score 0):

In parent, child table : "child_id <> parent_id" is obvious right , it will always fetch 99% of data then full table scan is better approach. Index will be slower if you selecting more percentage of data.

if your application needs "child_id <> parent_id" always then you can create check  constrain for the same. Then you may not need this where condition "child_id <> parent_id" any time.